# Global access of encrypted data in the cloud?

Tags: database, encryption, cloud-hosting, clouddb

Assuming that I created a cloud-based website application that people literally all over the world could use, are there any countries in particular that *do not* like personal data being encrypted and stored within a database and used in this manner?

I'm not saying about storing *unencrypted* data, I mean about countries that do not like the idea of their people storing data online in an encrypted form.

(I ask this after the United Arab Emirates recently stopped RIM's Blackberry devices working because of such encryption...)

Comment: What ?? I didn't know this. really. Its a vague rule. Its against Privacy. I'll keep my data doesn't matter how I want this. How the hell someone restrict me ?? Its so wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [place to start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_the_import_of_cryptography).  From what i can conclude, you should only have problems with countries that are somewhat totalitarian in nature.
EDIT:
It is not a complete list, and probably will never be a complete list because countries who abuse civil rights tend to not advertise this fact...

Comment: Good stuff - that's the best list I've been able to find!